# Magento2 - how to use user define function without use of helper?

Tags: php, magento

I have my own function for make developing easy.

Like :

```
function pr($data,$exit){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data);
    if($exit)
        die;
}


$collection=$this->pincodeCollection->create();
pr($collection->getData(),1);
```

Magento2 has helper concept but for helper function use we have to injection helper in constructor of class file.
So i want to avoid this step.

In magento2 any better way where we define our own functions. and use everywhere of php code.

Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can write a static method inside the class and then call the method from anywhere without dependency injection.

for example, you can see the below-given code in `Magento\Weee\Observer\AssignBackendModelToAttributeObserver`

```
$backendModel = \Magento\Weee\Model\Attribute\Backend\Weee\Tax::getBackendModelName();
```

Comment: Better provide a concrete answer with code example.

Comment: Hey @FranckGamess, as per your suggestion I've updated the solution with code example.